# create shell script to open two terminal with different programs in gdb with here document

Tags: bash, shell, gnome, gnome-terminal

I want to run two terminals with follwing options.

1)

```
gdb drizzle
```

2)

```
gdb drizzled << EOF
```

If I start the script with gnome-terminal or xterm it doesn't run the commands I give it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
xterm -e gdb drizzle
```

2)

```
xterm -e bash -c 'gdb drizzled <<EOF
heredoc ...
EOF'
```

The `-e` option to `xterm` doesn't run a shell, so you need to invoke `bash` explicitly if you want to use shell features like here-doc.

If you want the xterm to stick around after a command executes, use:

```
xterm -e bash -c 'command; echo Press return to exit; read x'
```

Comment: The xterm window disappears if I try to execute a very small program. any workaround?

Comment: Added that to answer.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. If I do 'gdb drizzled << EOF' and doesn't provide EOF in the end, it implicitly assumes EOF in the end and ends the gdb session. I want the gdb session to be active.

Comment: That's right. Bash's stdin is redirected to the -c argument, so reaching the end of the argument is EOF to bash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you added an extra `d` on your command:

```
gdb drizzled << EOF
```

Should perhaps be

```
gdb drizzle << EOF
```

Also it depends on the commands you placed after EOF.